# Finding the Largest Number in external variable

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers

Hi guys I wan to build a program with external variable but I have difficulties in displaying the number out when the program is debug.My program is to display the largest number in each column. For example, Biggest number in 88 98 88 98 and biggest nuber in 67 34 67 34 and so on. Can you guys help me?

First Source File

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    extern int transitTime[];
    int i;
    int number,largest;
    largest=0;
    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
    scanf_s("%d",&number);
    if(number>largest)largest=number;
    }
    printf("Largest=%d\n",largest);
}
```

Second Source File

```
int transitTime[] =
{
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //bus 8
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //bus15
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //22
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //23
};
```

Comment: What's seems to be the problem?

Comment: @40two The problem is that the largest number will not be displayed when i run the program

Comment: The largest number of what? The largest number of 11 user inputs is going to be displayed. Plus, `transitTime` is unused here.

Comment: Oh! How do find the largest number in the second source file?

Comment: `std::max_element(transitTime, transitTime + 44)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    //extern 
    int transitTime[] ={
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //bus 8
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //bus15
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //22
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //23
    };
    int i,j;
    int largest;

    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
    largest=0;
    printf("larger among ");

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
    printf("%d ",transitTime[i+j*11]);
    if(transitTime[i+j*11]>largest)largest=transitTime[i+j*11];
    }

    printf("is %d\n",largest);
    }
}
```